# can a native app access the web?

Tags: native

OK, after trolling the web I'm a little confused.

If I build a native app from html5 with something like Apache Cordova, can this app keep its offline database up to date with data from the web server?

Comment: HTML 5 has the capability of local storage as well as detecting online/offline so you can do what you want.

Comment: Cheers, we are looking into SQLite for the storage. But a collegue was convinced that any app which gained information from the web was a web app and as such could not be sold in the app store. From what I can see after our initial research is a web app is just a website optimized for mobile phones..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes We can do this using html5  server sent events. I did not try this but i guess it may helpful to u.[get data from server to client](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_serversentevents.asp)

[For caching](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_app_cache.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Off course it can. You'll "just" have to synchronize it when your application is connected to the internet.

Comment: Gracias! I thought this was the case, so basically syncing via ajax with jquery mobile...